# Populate form with JSON data from php script using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, populate

I'm populating a form with JSON data from a php script using AJAX. The input fields are being filled with the data when I click a button but not all of them are. It's like JQuery can't acces the whole DOM, although I'm using the "window.onload = function()". I've also tried with "jQuery(document).ready(function()". I've also putted my Javascript at the bottom of the  tag in the html page..

This is my function:

```
window.onload = function(){
        $('#button_dossier').click(function(){
            var clickBtnValue = $('#zipsearch').val();
            var ajaxurl = 'fill_form.php',
            data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                document.getElementById("datum_p").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("install").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("adres_t").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("vp").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("naam_vp").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("adres_vp").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("tel_vp").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("naam_oz").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("svc").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("tel_oz").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("c1").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("c2").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("c3").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("c").value = response.key;
                document.getElementById("opn").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("moti").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("hd").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("set").value =response.key;
                document.getElementById("ip").value =response.key;
            },'json');
        });
    };
```

What is going wrong here? Or is the function limited in lines?.

Thanks in advance!

---EDIT---

I've changed the "response[];" to "response.key;". This was my mistake..

Comment: What `response` are you getting? you should be using something like response['key'] or response.key.

Comment: `document.getElementById("datum_p").value = response[];` – that just makes no sense at all.

Comment: I've changed my script. I forgot to add my key to it. But it still doesn't work. Only 9 of the form elements get filled. The other ones are empty. For test purpose I've just used one key (named key) because I still got to write my php script.

Comment: Are you really putting the same object property into all the fields?

Comment: It's solved. I have removed all the "document.getElementById(id).value = response.key" with "$(#id).val(response.key);" and now all of the text fields get filled up.. . It seems that the getElementById function is limited or something. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The lines like

```
 document.getElementById("datum_p").value = response[];
```

will have no effect, since `response[]` is an L-Value and a shorthand for `array.push(value)`, What you probably mean is

```
 document.getElementById("datum_p").value = response["datum_p"];
```

which can be shortened in to (as you are using jQuery):

```
 function setField(key, response) {
     $('#' + key).val(response[key]);
 }
```

and furthermore:

```
 $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            $("#datum_pl").remove();
            setField("datum_p",response);
            ...
 });
```

To have it totaly generic, you may iterate over the properties of the response object, but then this must correspond to the form fields to 100%.

Comment: I've changed my script. I forgot to add my key to it. But it still doesn't work. Only 9 of the form elements get filled. The other ones are empty. For test purpose I've just used one key (named key) because I still got to write my php script.

Comment: It's solved. I have removed all the "document.getElementById(id).value = response.key" with "$(#id).val(response.key);" and now all of the text fields get filled up.. . It seems that the getElementById function is limited or something. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try https://github.com/dtuite/jquery.populate or the little more advanced http://uic.megaflop.net/download/. Each of them is a jQuery plugin dealing with serialization/deserialization of javascript/json data from / to html forms.